# How can I retrieve data from a database using PHP?

Tags: php, database

I have a problem with retrieving data from a database using PHP statements. At the moment the output looks like:

```
[{"Bez":"Cino"},{"Bez":"Extra"},{"Bez":"Panini"},{"Bez":"And so on"}]
```

"Bez" is the label of the column and we don't want it to be displayed. We just want to display the cell's contents so it should look like:

```
[Cino,Extra,Panini,And so on]
```

**The php is:**

```
<?php
  $username = "root";
  $database = "kaffeehaus";
  mysql_connect('localhost', $username);
  @mysql_select_db($database) or die("Geht nicht!");

  $query = "SELECT Bez FROM kategorie";
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error("error"));
  $num = mysql_numrows($result);

  mysql_close();

  $rows = array();
  while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
    $rows[] = $r;
  }

  echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
$rows[] = $r;
```

With

```
$rows[] = $r['Bez'];
```

...though to be honest, I'd replace the whole "fetch" part with:

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    $rows[] = $r[0];
```

That's because mysql_fetch_row is generally faster than mysql_fetch_assoc.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked just like it should be ;) . CI

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $rows[] = $r;
}`

with this:

`while ($r = mysql_fetch_array ($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $rows[] = $r['Bez'];
}`

Answer (score 0):

Use [mysql_fetch_row()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) instead (or `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);`). It fetches a numerical array so the column names are not shown.

Then, your output will look something like this:

```
[{"0":"Cino"},{"1":"Extra"},{"2":"Panini"},{"3":"And so on"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the json_encode part:

echo **json_encode**($rows); ?>

And use bez as row key:

echo ($rows['bez']); ?>

Answer (score 0):

And how does it work if there are more than one cell?

Our php looks like

```
<?php
 $username = "root";
 $database = "kaffeehaus";
 mysql_connect('localhost', $username);
 @mysql_select_db($database) or die("Geht nicht!");

 $ID_Kategorie = $_GET["Kategorie"];

 $query = "SELECT * FROM artikel WHERE ID_Kategorie=$ID_Kategorie";


 $result=mysql_query($query) or die("error");
 $num = mysql_numrows($result);

 mysql_close();

 $rows = array();
 while ($r  = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
    $rows = $r;

 }
 echo json_encode($rows);    ?>
```

And the output like:

```
[{"ID_Artikel": "12","ID_Kategorie":"19","Bez":"blabla","Beschreibung":"blabla"}]
```

But it schould look like:

```
[{"12","19","blabla","blabla"}]
```